# Knockout.js Pre-seed ObservableArray

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm not sure if I'm trying to do too much here, but here is the scenario.  I have an asp.net mvc page that, on the first time loading, returns a table of data in a view using the standard foreach mechanisms in the mvc framework.  If the user has javascript enabled, I want to use knockout to update the table going forward.  Is there a way to have knockout read the data from the dom table and use that data as the initial observable collection.  From then on out, I would use knockout and ajax to add, edit, or delete data.

In a nutshell, I need to parse an html table into a knockout observable collection.

Comment: You can set the initial data in a javascript variable and then add to observable instead of using foreach in the server.

Comment: What it the problem are you facing while doing this? It is completly possible,

Comment: @MuriloKunze: He says that JavaScript could be disabled. He can't use a JavaScript variable if JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: I'm trying to support both JavaScript and non-JavaScript scenarios. In both cases I initially load the page from the server.  However, if they do have JavaScript enabled, I want use JavaScript to "progressively enhance" the page.

Comment: Whats the question?  This is entirely possible.

Comment: The question is how do you do it?

Comment: You really shouldn't have to parse the html that you are generating. You should really just make the data available as JSON (or other js friendly format) and use the data directly. Or do an ajax call or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a go at coding this up:

Here's the basic markup:

```
<table id="table" data-bind="template: { name: 'table-template' }">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Richard</td>
      <td>Willis</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Here is the template we'll use for re-building the table -->

<script type="text/html" id="table-template">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: data">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: surname"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
(function() {

  function getTableData() {
    // http://johndyer.name/html-table-to-json/

    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    var data = [];
    var headers = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) { 
      headers[i] = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi, '');
    }
    // go through cells 
    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
      var tableRow = table.rows[i];
      var rowData = {};
      for (var j = 0; j < tableRow.cells.length; j++) {
        rowData[headers[j]] = tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML;
      }
      data.push(rowData);
    }

    return data;     
  }

  var Vm = function () {  
    this.data = ko.observableArray(getTableData());     
  };

  ko.applyBindings(new Vm(), document.getElementById('table'));
})();
```

You can extend this concept using the mapping plugin to create observables for each row: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

View a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/CShqK/1/

EDIT: I'm not saying this is the best approach, as it can be costly to traverse a large table to get the data. I would probably just output the JSON in the page as suggested by others in this thread.

Comment: Having spent a few days messing around with this stuff, I'm starting to think that mixing support for javascript and non-javascript browsers in the same view is just plain a bad idea.  I have yet to see an example online where it is done cleanly.  That being said, your solution works and deals with my concern of downloading the same data twice.  I ended up using Chris Fletcher's script, which essentially does the same thing:  http://www.fletchzone.com/post/jQuery-HTML-Table-to-JSON-Version-20!.aspx

Answer (score 0):

How about just feeding your observable array with the data instead of parsing the html table

```
myArray: ko.observableArray(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.myTableData)))
```

If you really need to go the parsing the html way, you can use the following code

```
var tableData = $('#myTable tr').map(function(){
return [
    $('td,th',this).map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get()
];
}).get();
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myData = JSON.stringify(tableData);
    alert(myData)
});
```

Here is a fiddle showing the code in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/FWCXH/

Comment: This does work; however, it now returns the data 2 times.  Once as html and once as json.  Does anyone know how to parse the html into json?

Comment: I added to my answer a javascript function that convert an html table to json